# migration from go-ethereum to java

Tags: go-ethereum, java

Our application is written using go-ethereum . We rely on few go packages from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi:

```
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/method.go
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/abi.go
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/argument.go
....
```

Now we are moving to java. What is a java package and classes which would an equivalent to these GoLang go-ethereum implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an Execution Client written in Java, there is Besu ([docs](https://besu.hyperledger.org/)). ethereum.org also currently (Jan 2024) maintains a page dedicated to Java development on Ethereum [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/java/), which may provide additional resources.